# What is the probability of observing three or fewer 6s when rolling a fair die twenty times?

Tags: probability

What is the probability of observing three or fewer 6s when rolling a fair die twenty times?

I am trying to figure this out..please be detailed on explaining. Thank you!

Comment: Any attempt from your side ? What is the probability observing one 6 ?

Comment: The easy part is the chance of observing no 6's in twenty rolls.  Please be detailed about your steps in "trying to figure this out".  Readers will find it easier to be helpful if you reveal your progress.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use the binomial distribution

You probably know the formula:

$$\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}p^k*(1-p)^{n-k}$$

Where $n$ is the amount of times you roll the dice
Where $k$ is the number of times you want to find
Where $p$ is the probability

You want to sum the chance of getting $0,1,2$ and $3$

And you are done

Comment: You will have to take the sum from k=0 to 3 of (20!)/((20-k)!*k!)*(1/6)^k*(1-(1/6))^(20-k)

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

Split it into **disjoint** events, and then add up their probabilities:

- The probability of observing "6" exactly $\color\red0$ times is $\binom{20}{\color\red0}\cdot\left(\frac16\right)^{\color\red0}\cdot\left(1-\frac16\right)^{20-\color\red0}$
- The probability of observing "6" exactly $\color\red1$ times is $\binom{20}{\color\red1}\cdot\left(\frac16\right)^{\color\red1}\cdot\left(1-\frac16\right)^{20-\color\red1}$
- The probability of observing "6" exactly $\color\red2$ times is $\binom{20}{\color\red2}\cdot\left(\frac16\right)^{\color\red2}\cdot\left(1-\frac16\right)^{20-\color\red2}$
- The probability of observing "6" exactly $\color\red3$ times is $\binom{20}{\color\red3}\cdot\left(\frac16\right)^{\color\red3}\cdot\left(1-\frac16\right)^{20-\color\red3}$

---

Hence the overall probability is:

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{3}\binom{20}{n}\cdot\left(\frac16\right)^{n}\cdot\left(1-\frac16\right)^{20-n}\approx56.65\%$$